# Fiery Server Needs SSL connection from internal and external but No domain to create certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate

We have a Fiery Server that needs SSL connection from internal and external devices but the server does not have a public domain in order to create the certificate. Any recommendations on how to configure this network so we can have https access external to the firewall and also https from inside the network? This server was initially setup with only a hostname and internal IP.

Also, our external developer is hitting our FW IP and getting "state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate) (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Obtain Let's Encrypt SSL Certificate for Internal Server on Internal DNS Server](https://serverfault.com/questions/1078367/obtain-lets-encrypt-ssl-certificate-for-internal-server-on-internal-dns-server)

Comment: Obtain a domain name first perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

The server itself doesn't need a "public domain". Assuming your company has a registered domain, you need to generate a CSR for the "friendly" or common name for the certificate (fiery.yourdomain.com), then you need to purchase an SSL certificate for that name, then you need to install the certificate on your Fiery server, configure the site or application on the server for that name and certificate, then update your external and internal DNS and firewalls accordingly so that the name can be resolved to the server public ip address.